# Binding each datagridrow to a class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an Item class which has 2 properties, "Value" and "IsSelected". The "Value" format is something like "Column1=Value1::Column2=Value2::Column3=Value3", and "IsSelected" is a boolean value.

I have a list of this Item class, which I need to bind to a datagrid. So, basically I need to split the "Value" string and construct a DataTable to bind it to the datagrid. Then, if the Item's "IsSelected" is true, I will need to color the row with a color.

The problem I'm having is, I do not know how can I present my data in a datagrid while checking the "IsSelected" property to set the row color. How can I bind my data such that each datarow is binding to each Item class?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with binding?

Comment: Hi Bruno, yes I am. I know that I can bind the list to the DataGrid's ItemSource, but then I can't access the "IsSelected" property for each of the row then.

Comment: Is your Datagrid creating the columns automatically? Or you define manually?

Comment: The DataGrid columns are automatically created. The number of columns are undefined. I think I missed explaining a part. If the "Value" is "Column1=Value1::Column2=Value2::Column3=Value3", it means that I need to have 3 columns. So the number of columns depends on the "Value". It can have 3 columns, 4 columns, or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could style your DataGridRow, here's an example:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I just did a silly example, however, you just have to write your on style in order to bind your property IsSelected in which row, in my case, I create a Datatrigger which is based on the value of the property IsSelected, just like your case, and whenever the value of this property is true, I change the background of my row to green.

And that is it, it works like expected.
[image]

Comment: Hi Bruno. The "Value" is not just a simple value like what you had. The "Value" that I will be having is like "Name=Sherlock::Age=11::Gender=Male", where Name, Age, and Gender represent 3 columns in the datagrid. So I will need to split the "Value" and build a datatable out of it. Then, I'll need to bind the datatable to the datagrid. So, its not as simple as just having Value and IsSelected in the datagrid. Also, IsSelected will not be visible in the UI. I'll try your approach to see if it works :)

Comment: Sure, just like I said, this is a silly example, you just have to adapt it for your need.

Comment: So, the fact that I need to parse the "Value" to create a datatable, then bind to the datagrid, are each row still binding to each "Item"? I don't think so right?

Comment: Yeah, once your list on Viewmodel is binded to the DataGrid, which item on the list represents a row on Datagrid.

Comment: One thing I think weird, if your Datagrid columns are not defined, aren't some columns will be empty for certain rows?

Comment: Yes, so probably the Value will be like "Name=Sherlock::Age=::Gender=Male". In this case, the age is empty for this row.

Comment: I tried your method, it works by displaying 2 columns, Value and IsSelected, but unfortunately I'll need to split the Value into more colums, which means I can't do a direct binding :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94701/discussion-between-bruno-joaquim-and-dhinnesh-jeevan).